# How would one leverage the OpenFDA API to obtain listing of all recalls associated with a specific CIED?

Tags: api, openfda

How would one leverage the OpenFDA API to obtain listing of all recalls associated with a specific CIED?  We have limited info on each device such as the model of implanted device and serial number.  We do not have manufacturing data or lot info.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the Device Recall Enforcement endpoint in openFDA with the information you have available. For example, if you have a device model name, you could query against the `product_description` field, which often contains model name, number or other relevant information:

https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?search=product_description:IMPLANTABLE%20CARDIOVERTER%20DEFIBRILLATOR

Serial as well as model numbers often appear in the `code_info` field:

https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?search=code_info:BWB202998H

Please note: due to "imprecise" nature of these search queries you are **not** guaranteed to obtain a *complete* list of recalls associated with a particular device.